How Does Berkeley's View of Reality Integrate Free Will and God's Story?
I’m trying to better understand Berkeley's view of reality. From what I gather, things exist only if we perceive them. In Sophie’s World, for example, characters exist solely in the mind of God (or the author), and they can reappear in my mind as a reader once I perceive them. This is the only way inanimate objects become 'real'—by being perceived either by us or by God.
Applying this idea to our larger reality, Berkeley seems to suggest that everything we experience is part of a story written by God. For instance, when I see the moon rise at night, it's like I’m reading a chapter of God's narrative.
From what I understand, Berkeley also believes that humans possess free will. If that’s the case, how does this free will fit into God's story? For example, imagine there’s a scenario where a dog is near me and I’m about to be bitten. Am I free to choose between actions, like in the Black Mirror episode 'Bandersnatch,' where we can pick an option—kick the dog or walk away—once I do, the "show" continues?
Additionally, could the analogy of the Matrix work here too where machines and their world are abstracted away into a single concept called God and humans plugged into the Matrix be considered as representing the Berkeley's spirit concept?

In the notebooks, "Berkeley is how to make sense of the causal powers that he ascribes to spirits. [...] he revises [the Humean view that a cause is whatever is regularly followed by an effect] by requiring that a cause not only (regularly) precede an effect but also be a volition. Berkeley’s talk of occasion here reveals the immediate influence of Malebranche. Malebranche held that the only true cause is God and that apparent finite causes are only “occasional causes”.

Occasional “causes” thus regularly precede their “effects” but are not truly responsible for producing them. In these notebook entries, however, Berkeley seems to be suggesting that all there is to causality is this regular consequence, with the first item being a volition. Such an account, unlike Malebranche’s, would make my will and God’s will causes in exactly the same thin sense."

@MauroALLEGRANZA so basically spirit is free to move a ball, but only in a trajectory that is allowed by God's idea of possible trajectories?

Mybe spirit is free to move a foot to kick the ball that will move in a trajectory allowed by rules of mechanics that are compliant to God's volition.

Says Berkeley:"We move our Legs our selves. ‘tis we that will their movement. Herein I differ from Malbranch." McDonough argues that Berkeley's position is concurrentism, "subordinate to the supreme agent there is a cause of a limited and inferior nature, which concurs in the production of our ideas." In a nutshell, God enables human agents to co-author the story in small ways, erratic though they are, "the ideas of sense… are not excited at random, as those which are the effects of human wills often are, but in a regular train or series."
